# Is it possible to include emoji in the app description in the App Store? Wouldn't the app be rejected or banned?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have an app listed in the App Store. Don't you know is it possible to use emoji in the description of the app or use any kind of text formatting (italic, bold, underline)? 
I have found the information about apps that were rejected due to use of Apple emoji in their icons but nothing is written about description/what's new/promotional text fields.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your question, Anastasia. Using emoji is not against the guidelines of Apple. Here you will find several tips you should be aware of: https://splitmetrics.com/blog/apple-app-store-guidelines/

Here you find an example in practical terms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891204/additional-icon-in-app-name-lable

However, I think emojis should be used carefully, depending on what target group you want to reach and what you want to achieve...

Cheers, pallox

Comment: @AnastasiaKomarova if my answer solves your question, feel free to mark it as a solution :)